# How do I group my results based on condition - SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, group-by

I have following table.

```
CustomerID  Country  company   email           invoice
01          USA      A         abc@gmail.com   100
02          USA      B         bng@yahoo.com   150
03          Canada   C         abc@gmail.com   100
04          Aus      D         bng@yahoo.com   150
```

I want to have:

For the countries that have at least two customers using yahoo as e-mail provider, display those countries along with the sum of invoice. Sum should only include the invoices from customers using yahoo. (Group by Country)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply filter the email by domain and do aggregation for those countries where count is atleast 2.

```
select country, sum(invoice) sum_of_invoice
from your_table
where email like '%@yahoo.com'
group by country
having count(*) >= 2;
```

If you want to further include other similar domain like `@yahoo.co.uk` etc, then you can use `email like '%@yahoo.%'` in the where clause.

If you want to get sum of invoices of all the customers in the country which has atleast 2 yahoo as providers, then:

```
select country,
    sum(invoice) sum_of_invoice
from your_table
group by country
having count(case when email like '%@yahoo.com' then 1 end) >= 2;
```

Comment: thank you so much. If I want to to get the sum of invoice of all customers with given same condition that the countries have at least two customers using yahoo as an e-mail provider. How can I achieve this? .

Comment: @MyurathanKajendran - Updated the answer. See the second query